# Set cookie in HttpWebRequest from C# WinApp

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to make a **HttpWebRequest** from c# winapp.

I have got the following request headers from google chrome developers tool (omitted unnecessary parts)-

```
Cookie: PHPSESSID=f530kslitnsq7uho33auebkd11;ciIPPBXOBd=TOAf5yvdIlHf7Ak%3D
```

My code is -

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("example.com");
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("PHPSESSID", "f533auebkd11") { Domain = "example.com" };
request.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
```

But I am getting object reference null error in the last line.

How to get rid of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default cookie container is null. 
try this.

```
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("PHPSESSID", "f533auebkd11") { Domain = "example.com" };
        //if cookie contaner is null then try new container
        request.CookieContainer =  request.CookieContainer ?? new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
```